# Rails 4 : How to send http request for sms API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using 
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]
Rails 4.2.4

i have sms integration API which needs to send http request like below

```
http://123.63.33.43//blank/sms/user/urlsmstemp.php?username=XXXX&pass=XXXX&senderid=XXXX&dest_mobileno=#XXXX&tempid=45902&response=Y
```

i need to execute it background after creating a record. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [RestClient](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) for make any kind of third party API call and for background job you can use [Delayed::Job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: RestClient.get 'http://123.63.33.43//blank/sms/user/urlsmstemp.php?username=XXXX&pass=XXXX&senderid=XXXX&dest_mobileno=#XXXX&tempid=45902&response=Y'  shows bad URl

Comment: i appended..forgot to include in comment..result same

Comment: what i postman? i tried url in browser its working.. and for redirecting also it working..

Comment: http://www.smsjust.com/blank/sms/user/urlsmstemp.php?username=XXXX&pass=XXXX&senderid=EBSRVC&dest_mobileno=9866106019&tempid=45902&F1=XXXX&F2=XXXX&F3=XXXX&F4=XX&F5=XX&F6=XX&F7=XX&F8=XX&F9=XX&F10=XX&F11=XX&response=Y

Comment: Great, Keep coding :)